# Removing the end of a string after a certain character in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to end my string after a certain character in C. This program will work with the file system so the character will be repeated, I need the find the last occurence of that character end delete everything after that.

I found something from the internet but that doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteEnd (char* myStr){

    printf ("%s\n", myStr);
    char *del = &myStr[strlen(myStr)];

    while (del > myStr && *del != '/')
        del--;

    if (*del== '/')
        *del= '\0'; // the program crashes here

    return;
}

int main ( void )
{

    char* foo= "/one/two/three/two";
    deleteEnd(foo);
    printf ("%s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

this code basically finds the last '/' character and places the null terminator there. It works theorically but not practically.

By the way if my way is wrong, is there any better way to do this?

Thank you.

**edit: I replaced my code with "strrchr()" upon the suggestions but still got no result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteEnd (char* myStr){

    char *lastslash;

    if (lastslash = strrchr(myStr, '/'))
        *lastslash = '\0'; // the code still crashes here.

    return;
}

int main ( void )
{

    char* foo= "/one/two/three/two";
    deleteEnd(foo);
    printf ("%s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *lastslash; if (lastslash = strrchr(myStr, '/')) *lastslash = '\0';`

Comment: Your code is trying to modify a constant string that foo is pointing to. Try copying it to a char array first, and also start your assignment of 'del' from strlen(mystr)-1 which is the last byte that is actually contained in the string. Anyway, doing pointer arithmetic like this is not a good idea, so using a lookup from the end to the beginning is better, either with a loop, or strrchr().

Comment: @DNT: I think you're wrong about `strlen()-1`. Consider an empty string: `strlen("")` is zero, and you certainly don't want to reference `strlen("")-1`.

Comment: @EOF This empty string condition should be checked too before anything else and the code should jus return without attempting to change anything. Same when no '/' is found.. However strlen(s) when s is "abcde" is 5, but indices in the array would be from 0 to 4. Index 5 is one byte outside.

Comment: @DNT: `str[strlen(str)]` is not invalid, if `str` is a valid string, it is *always* zero. That's kinda the point.

Comment: @EOF can you give an example of what valid element of the string str[strlen(str)] is referencing when str is "abcde" ? If you are refering to the zero terminator, then ok, but this is not searching the items for '/'

Comment: @DNT: The string "abcde" is really `str[0]='a',str[1]='b',str[2]='c',str[3]='d',str[4]='e',str[5]='\0'`. `strlen("abcde")` is 5. You see `str[5] = '\0'`? That's a valid element of the string. It *has to be*, because it is *read* by string-handling functions.

Comment: @EOF Yes, yes, I know. It's all a matter of where I'd start the search wanting to avoid the zero terminator, that was the meaning of my comment, not that it is invalid in the sense that it lies outside the allocated space for the array. In the case of empty string though, starting from there may actually be better since this is also the beginning of the string. Point taken.

Comment: @DNT: I see. It would be a silly micro-optimization to start from the byte *before* the null-terminator, especially because of the empty string. Also, for fun: It's even valid to do `char *ptr = &str[strlen(str)+1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, When you write literal strings like this:
char* foo= "/one/two/three/two";

Those are immutable, which means they are embedded in the executable and are read only.

You get an access violation (crash) when trying to modify read only data.

Instead you can declare your string as an array of chars instead of a literal string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteEnd (char* myStr){

    printf ("%s\n", myStr);
    char *del = &myStr[strlen(myStr)];

    while (del > myStr && *del != '/')
        del--;

    if (*del== '/')
        *del= '\0';

    return;
}

int main ( void )
{

    char foo[] = "/one/two/three/two";
    deleteEnd(foo);
    printf ("%s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it spend too much space if this code repeats? I'm planning to place this fragment into a recursive function, so I guess it would. is there a way to lower the memory needed?

Comment: Declare the string as an array instead of a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

yeschar *lastslash;

```
if (lastslash = strrchr(myStr, '/'))
    *lastslash = '\0'; // the code still crashes here.

return;
```

}

int main ( void )
{

```
char foo[]= "/one/two/three/two";
deleteEnd(foo);
printf ("%s\n", foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start at the first character.
2. Scan the current character, is it /? No? Go to step 3. Yes? Go to step 4.
3. Is there another character? No? Go to step 5. Yes? Go to the next character and go to step 2.
4. Set a "lastSlash" variable to current character position. Go to step 2.
5. Delete everything after lastSlash's position. You're done!

Comment: I think I'm trying to do what you said here. I'm looking from backwards so I directly find the character, trying to delete the rest but fail. Honestly, what you said is not helpful.

Comment: I take it you don't actually know C? I don't have time atm to type this up for you but i'll do it later if none of the other answers have.

Comment: I take it you don't actually read my question? I don't need any followup, I got my answer. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `foo` as an array of chars, instead of a pointer to a char:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteEnd (char* myStr){

    char *lastslash;

    if (lastslash = strrchr(myStr, '/'))
        *lastslash = '\0'; // the code still crashes here.

    return;
}

int main ( void )
{

    char foo[]= "/one/two/three/two";
    deleteEnd(foo);
    printf ("%s\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I still use the functions like realloc(), strdup() or strcat() etc. if I do this?

Comment: `realloc()` can be used only on memory allocated by `malloc()` or `realloc()` itself and memory for `foo` has not been allocated that way. `strcat()` works as long as the maximum size of the array is not exceded. That is, the number of bytes that were assigned to the array upon its initialization. `strdup()` can be used with string `foo` with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change in a string constant, you must copy to a new char string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void delete_end(char* dest, const char* source)
{
    const char* p = source + strlen(source) - 1;
    while(*p != '/' && p > source)
        --p;
    strncpy(dest, source, p - source);
    dest[p-source] = '\0';
}

int main()
{

    const char* str = "one/two/three/four";
    char buf[256];
    delete_end(buf, str);
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is overly complicated. You may simply obtain a copy in the first place.... `char str[] = "one/two/three/four";` no need for `strncpy` or excess buffers or any of that.

Answer (score 0):

to find the last occurrence of a character in a string in C, use the `strrchr(3)` function. Its prototype is in *<string.h>*.